# using execute immediate to insert into

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Seems to work fine outside the procedure but when inside the procedure it doesn't seem to do anything . The procedure complies and runs without error but doesn't insert any rows. Can anyone help me, please.

```
create or replace procedure sp_retail_transaction_insert 
authid current_user
as
begin
  execute immediate ('
  insert into sp_retail_transaction 
  (indiv_id, perm_id, acct_type, acct_source, tender_cd, trans_header_id, trans_datetime_full,
  trans_type, tot_price_amt, promotion_code, store_name, store_type, store_cat, store_terminal_location, store_area_location, cmp_period, staff)
  select 
  a.indiv_id, 
  a.perm_id,
  a.acct_type,
  a.acct_source,
  a.tender_cd,
  a.trans_header_id,
  a.trans_datetime_full,
  a.trans_type,
  a.tot_price_amt,
  a.promotion_code,
  a.company_name as store_name,
  a.site_type as store_type,
  a.secondary_site_type as store_cat,
  a.airport_terminal as store_terminal_location,
  a.building_desc as store_area_location,
  case when 
  trans_datetime_full between to_date(b.start_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') 
  and 
  to_date (b.end_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') then ''cmp_period''
  when to_date(trans_datetime_full, ''dd/mm/yyyy'')<to_date(b.start_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') then ''pre_cmp_period''
  when to_date(trans_datetime_full, ''dd/mm/yyyy'')>to_date(b.end_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') then ''post_cmp_period''
  end as cmp_period,
  case when c.staff_flag = 1 or c.staff_flag_revised = 1 or c.pseudo_staff_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end as staff
  from sp_temp b, tableau.an_retail_trans_full a 
  left join tableau.an_individual_tb_full  c
  on a.indiv_id=c.indiv_id
  where a.tot_price_amt>0 and 
  a.indiv_id is not null and

      (   instr ('','' || upper(b.airport_terminal)|| '','', '','' ||upper(a.airport_terminal)|| '','') <> 0 or upper(b.airport_terminal) is null) and 
          (   instr ('','' || upper(b.store_name) || '','', '','' || upper(a.loc_desc_long) || '','') <> 0 or upper(b.store_name) is null) and 
          (   instr ('','' || upper(b.acct_type) || '','' , '','' || upper(a.acct_type) || '','') <> 0 or upper(b.acct_type) is null) and
          (   instr ('','' || upper(b.trans_type) || '','', '','' || upper(a.trans_type) || '','') <> 0 or upper(b.trans_type) is null) 
  and
  a.trans_datetime_full between (to_date(b.start_date,''dd/mm/yyyy'')-( to_date (b.end_date,''dd/mm/yyyy'') - to_date(b.start_date,''dd/mm/yyyy''))) 
  and 
  (to_date (b.end_date,''dd/mm/yyyy'')+( to_date (b.end_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'') - to_date(b.start_date, ''dd/mm/yyyy'')))');
end sp_retail_transaction_insert;
```

Comment: Why use dynamic SQL at all?

Comment: Don't forget to commit.

Comment: I am using SQL Developer for coding.

Comment: @mustaccio: I am using dynamic SQL because its part of an automation, there are totally 15 procedure put together in a package. The one mentioned here is the second procedure.

Comment: Yes but there's nothing in the code you've posted here which justifies the use of dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Gary_W: I committed it but still no good. Doesn't insert any rows

Comment: @APC: the above code uses four tables, for example t1, t2, t3 t4.           Two tables t1 and t2 are joined and the values are inserted into table t4, Values from table t3 are used in the where condition, but there is no joining key between the tables. I assumes that the only way of putting it together in a procedure was using dynamic SQL. Can you recommend using any other way in a proceudre.

Comment: yes, that's what INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM does. That doesn't require dynamic SQL. Just put the SQL in the procedure. We only need to use Dynamic SQL when we're **conditionally** changing the SQL e.g. changing the target table on the basis of some input parameter

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If commit is not issues in the session executing the insert, the records will be not be available to other sessions until commit is issued.  If session exits before commit, then records are rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Partition by comma delimiter

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CA_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_INSERT   AUTHID CURRENT_USER   AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CA_RETAIL_TRANSACTION   SELECT A.INDIV_ID, 
A.PERM_ID,
  A.ACCT_TYPE,
    A.ACCT_SOURCE,
      A.TENDER_CD,
        A.TRANS_HEADER_ID,
          A.TRANS_DATETIME_FULL,
            A.TRANS_TYPE,
              A.TOT_PRICE_AMT,
                A.PROMOTION_CODE,
                  A.COMPANY_NAME AS STORE_NAME,
                    A.SITE_TYPE AS STORE_TYPE,
                      A.SECONDARY_SITE_TYPE AS STORE_CAT,
                        A.AIRPORT_TERMINAL AS STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION,
                          A.BUILDING_DESC AS STORE_AREA_LOCATION,

                        CASE WHEN 
                      TRANS_DATETIME_FULL 

                  BETWEEN B.START_DATE 
                AND B.END_DATE 
              THEN 'CMP_PERIOD'

            WHEN TRANS_DATETIME_FULL < 
          B.START_DATE 
        THEN 'PRE_CMP_PERIOD'

     WHEN 
    TRANS_DATETIME_FULL> 
  B.END_DATE
 THEN 'POST_CMP_PERIOD'
END AS CMP_PERIOD,

CASE when 
  C.Staff_Flag = 1 OR 
    C.Staff_Flag_Revised = 1 OR 
      C.Pseudo_Staff_Flag = 1 
        then 1 else 0 
END AS Staff

FROM TABLEAU.AN_RETAIL_TRANS_FULL A

  JOIN 
    CA_TEMP B
      ON 
      A.TRANS_DATETIME_FULL BETWEEN
    B.PRE_START_DATE AND
      B.POST_END_DATE 


  left JOIN
    TABLEAU.AN_INDIVIDUAL_TB_FULL C
      ON
      A.INDIV_ID = C.INDIV_ID

WHERE 
  A.TRANS_DATETIME_FULL BETWEEN
    B.PRE_START_DATE AND
      B.POST_END_DATE AND

A.TOT_PRICE_AMT > 0 AND
      A.INDIV_ID IS NOT NULL  AND

    (   INSTR (',' || UPPER(B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL)|| ',', 
               ',' || UPPER(A.AIRPORT_TERMINAL)|| ',') <> 0 OR 
                      UPPER(B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL) IS NULL) AND 

        (   INSTR (',' || UPPER(B.STORE_NAME) || ',', 
                   ',' || UPPER(A.COMPANY_NAME) || ',') <> 0 OR 
                          UPPER(B.STORE_NAME) IS NULL) AND 

            (   INSTR (',' || UPPER(B.ACCT_TYPE) || ',' , 
                       ',' || UPPER(A.ACCT_TYPE) || ',') <> 0 OR 
                               UPPER(B.ACCT_TYPE) IS NULL) AND

                (   INSTR (',' || UPPER(B.TRANS_TYPE) || ',', 
                           ',' || UPPER(A.TRANS_TYPE) || ',') <> 0 OR 
                                  UPPER(B.TRANS_TYPE) IS NULL) ;
```

END CA_RETAIL_TRANSACTION_INSERT;